# improving query times a sql ip lookup database

Tags: sql, sql-server, ip-address, geocoding, ip

I have a table in sql server 2005 which holds an ip range and the corresponding info (country / city / etc).  There are approximately 3 million rows and it currently takes just over half a second to return a record based on the query below.

```
DECLARE @ip BIGINT
SELECT @ip=3561360969

SELECT TOP 1 id, ipfrom, ipto, countrycode, countryname,region,city
FROM tbl_ip 
WHERE ipfrom <= @ip and @ip <= ipto
```

Can anyone offer any suggestions to improve the query time as the system I'm building needs to handle about 10 of these queries a second.  I've already done the following which hasn't improved the query time much...

- Set the database to read only
- Used the NOLOCK table hint
- Indexed the ipfrom & ipto columns

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Tim

Edit:
The xml execution plan is below:

```
<ShowPlanXML xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan" Version="1.0" Build="9.00.4053.00"><BatchSequence><Batch><Statements><StmtSimple StatementText="set statistics time on&#xd;&#xa;&#xd;" StatementId="1" StatementCompId="1" StatementType="SET STATS"/><StmtSimple StatementText="&#xa;DECLARE @ip BIGINT&#xd;&#xa;SELECT @ip=3561360969&#xd;" StatementId="2" StatementCompId="2" StatementType="ASSIGN"/><StmtSimple StatementText="&#xa;SELECT top 1 id, ipfrom, ipto, countrycode, countryname,region,city&#xd;&#xa;FROM tbl_ip &#xd;&#xa;WHERE ipfrom &lt;= @ip and @ip &lt;= ipto&#xd;&#xa;&#xd;" StatementId="3" StatementCompId="3" StatementType="SELECT" StatementSubTreeCost="0.00337934" StatementEstRows="1" StatementOptmLevel="TRIVIAL"><StatementSetOptions QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="false" ARITHABORT="true" CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL="false" ANSI_NULLS="false" ANSI_PADDING="false" ANSI_WARNINGS="false" NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT="false"/><QueryPlan CachedPlanSize="8" CompileTime="0" CompileCPU="0" CompileMemory="120"><RelOp NodeId="0" PhysicalOp="Top" LogicalOp="Top" EstimateRows="1" EstimateIO="0" EstimateCPU="1e-007" AvgRowSize="393" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.00337934" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0"><OutputList><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="Id"/><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="IPFrom"/><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="IPTo"/><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="CountryCode"/><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="CountryName"/><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="Region"/><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="City"/></OutputList><Top RowCount="0" IsPercent="0" WithTies="0"><TopExpression><ScalarOperator ScalarString="(1)"><Const ConstValue="(1)"/></ScalarOperator></TopExpression><RelOp NodeId="1" PhysicalOp="Clustered Index Scan" LogicalOp="Clustered Index Scan" EstimateRows="1" EstimateIO="28.1505" EstimateCPU="3.77105" AvgRowSize="393" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.00337724" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0"><OutputList><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="Id"/><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="IPFrom"/><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="IPTo"/><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="CountryCode"/><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="CountryName"/><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="Region"/><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="City"/></OutputList><IndexScan Ordered="0" ForcedIndex="0" NoExpandHint="0"><DefinedValues><DefinedValue><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="Id"/></DefinedValue><DefinedValue><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="IPFrom"/></DefinedValue><DefinedValue><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="IPTo"/></DefinedValue><DefinedValue><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="CountryCode"/></DefinedValue><DefinedValue><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="CountryName"/></DefinedValue><DefinedValue><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="Region"/></DefinedValue><DefinedValue><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="City"/></DefinedValue></DefinedValues><Object Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Index="[PK_tbl_IP2]"/><Predicate><ScalarOperator ScalarString="[RecruitmentIP].[dbo].[tbl_IP].[IPFrom]&lt;=[@ip] AND [@ip]&lt;=[RecruitmentIP].[dbo].[tbl_IP].[IPTo]"><Logical Operation="AND"><ScalarOperator><Compare CompareOp="LE"><ScalarOperator><Identifier><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="IPFrom"/></Identifier></ScalarOperator><ScalarOperator><Identifier><ColumnReference Column="@ip"/></Identifier></ScalarOperator></Compare></ScalarOperator><ScalarOperator><Compare CompareOp="LE"><ScalarOperator><Identifier><ColumnReference Column="@ip"/></Identifier></ScalarOperator><ScalarOperator><Identifier><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="IPTo"/></Identifier></ScalarOperator></Compare></ScalarOperator></Logical></ScalarOperator></Predicate></IndexScan></RelOp></Top></RelOp></QueryPlan></StmtSimple><StmtSimple StatementText="&#xa;set statistics time off" StatementId="4" StatementCompId="4" StatementType="SET STATS"/></Statements></Batch></BatchSequence></ShowPlanXML>
```

Execution plan with index on ipfrom, ipto

```
<ShowPlanXML xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan" Version="1.0" Build="9.00.4053.00"><BatchSequence><Batch><Statements><StmtSimple StatementText="DECLARE @ip BIGINT&#xd;&#xa;SELECT @ip=3561360969&#xd;" StatementId="1" StatementCompId="1" StatementType="ASSIGN"/><StmtSimple StatementText="&#xa;SELECT top 1 id, ipfrom, ipto, countrycode, countryname,region,city&#xd;&#xa;FROM tbl_ip &#xd;&#xa;WHERE ipfrom &lt;= @ip and @ip &lt;= ipto&#xd;&#xa;ORDER BY ipto&#xd;&#xa;" StatementId="2" StatementCompId="2" StatementType="SELECT" StatementSubTreeCost="224.264" StatementEstRows="1" StatementOptmLevel="FULL"><StatementSetOptions QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="false" ARITHABORT="true" CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL="false" ANSI_NULLS="false" ANSI_PADDING="false" ANSI_WARNINGS="false" NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT="false"/><QueryPlan CachedPlanSize="10" CompileTime="1" CompileCPU="1" CompileMemory="160"><RelOp NodeId="0" PhysicalOp="Sort" LogicalOp="TopN Sort" EstimateRows="1" EstimateIO="182.872" EstimateCPU="6.45397" AvgRowSize="393" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="224.264" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0"><OutputList><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="Id"/><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="IPFrom"/><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="IPTo"/><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="CountryCode"/><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="CountryName"/><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="Region"/><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="City"/></OutputList><MemoryFractions Input="0" Output="1"/><TopSort Distinct="0" Rows="1"><OrderBy><OrderByColumn Ascending="1"><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="IPTo"/></OrderByColumn></OrderBy><RelOp NodeId="1" PhysicalOp="Clustered Index Scan" LogicalOp="Clustered Index Scan" EstimateRows="308528" EstimateIO="28.1505" EstimateCPU="3.77105" AvgRowSize="393" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="31.9216" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0"><OutputList><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="Id"/><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="IPFrom"/><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="IPTo"/><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="CountryCode"/><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="CountryName"/><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="Region"/><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="City"/></OutputList><IndexScan Ordered="0" ForcedIndex="0" NoExpandHint="0"><DefinedValues><DefinedValue><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="Id"/></DefinedValue><DefinedValue><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="IPFrom"/></DefinedValue><DefinedValue><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="IPTo"/></DefinedValue><DefinedValue><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="CountryCode"/></DefinedValue><DefinedValue><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="CountryName"/></DefinedValue><DefinedValue><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="Region"/></DefinedValue><DefinedValue><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="City"/></DefinedValue></DefinedValues><Object Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Index="[PK_tbl_IP2]"/><Predicate><ScalarOperator ScalarString="[RecruitmentIP].[dbo].[tbl_IP].[IPFrom]&lt;=[@ip] AND [@ip]&lt;=[RecruitmentIP].[dbo].[tbl_IP].[IPTo]"><Logical Operation="AND"><ScalarOperator><Compare CompareOp="LE"><ScalarOperator><Identifier><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="IPFrom"/></Identifier></ScalarOperator><ScalarOperator><Identifier><ColumnReference Column="@ip"/></Identifier></ScalarOperator></Compare></ScalarOperator><ScalarOperator><Compare CompareOp="LE"><ScalarOperator><Identifier><ColumnReference Column="@ip"/></Identifier></ScalarOperator><ScalarOperator><Identifier><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="IPTo"/></Identifier></ScalarOperator></Compare></ScalarOperator></Logical></ScalarOperator></Predicate></IndexScan></RelOp></TopSort></RelOp></QueryPlan></StmtSimple></Statements></Batch></BatchSequence></ShowPlanXML>
```

execution plan for Martin Smiths query:

```
<ShowPlanXML xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan" Version="1.0" Build="9.00.4053.00"><BatchSequence><Batch><Statements><StmtSimple StatementText="--set showplan_xml on&#xd;&#xa;&#xd;&#xa;set statistics time on&#xd;&#xa;&#xd;" StatementId="1" StatementCompId="1" StatementType="SET STATS"/><StmtSimple StatementText="&#xa;DECLARE @ip BIGINT&#xd;&#xa;SELECT @ip=3561360969&#xd;&#xa;&#xd;" StatementId="2" StatementCompId="2" StatementType="ASSIGN"/><StmtSimple StatementText="&#xa;SELECT id, ipfrom, ipto, countrycode, countryname,region,city FROM&#xd;&#xa;(&#xd;&#xa;SELECT TOP 1 id, ipfrom, ipto, countrycode, countryname,region,city&#xd;&#xa;FROM tbl_ip &#xd;&#xa;WHERE @ip &lt;= ipto&#xd;&#xa;ORDER BY ipto&#xd;&#xa;INTERSECT&#xd;&#xa;SELECT TOP 1 id, ipfrom, ipto, countrycode, countryname,region,city&#xd;&#xa;FROM tbl_ip &#xd;&#xa;WHERE ipfrom &lt;= @ip&#xd;&#xa;ORDER BY ipfrom DESC&#xd;&#xa;) ip&#xd;&#xa;&#xd;" StatementId="3" StatementCompId="3" StatementType="SELECT" StatementSubTreeCost="226.409" StatementEstRows="1" StatementOptmLevel="FULL"><StatementSetOptions QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="false" ARITHABORT="true" CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL="false" ANSI_NULLS="false" ANSI_PADDING="false" ANSI_WARNINGS="false" NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT="false"/><QueryPlan CachedPlanSize="33" CompileTime="6" CompileCPU="6" CompileMemory="376"><MissingIndexes><MissingIndexGroup Impact="10.1146"><MissingIndex Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]"><ColumnGroup Usage="INEQUALITY"><Column Name="[IPTo]" ColumnId="3"/></ColumnGroup><ColumnGroup Usage="INCLUDE"><Column Name="[Id]" ColumnId="1"/><Column Name="[IPFrom]" ColumnId="2"/><Column Name="[CountryCode]" ColumnId="4"/><Column Name="[CountryName]" ColumnId="5"/><Column Name="[Region]" ColumnId="6"/><Column Name="[City]" ColumnId="7"/></ColumnGroup></MissingIndex></MissingIndexGroup></MissingIndexes><RelOp NodeId="0" PhysicalOp="Nested Loops" LogicalOp="Left Semi Join" EstimateRows="1" EstimateIO="0" EstimateCPU="4.18e-006" AvgRowSize="86" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="226.409" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0"><OutputList><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="Id"/><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="IPFrom"/><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="IPTo"/><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="CountryCode"/><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="CountryName"/><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="Region"/><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="City"/></OutputList><NestedLoops Optimized="0"><Predicate><ScalarOperator ScalarString="[RecruitmentIP].[dbo].[tbl_IP].[Id]=[RecruitmentIP].[dbo].[tbl_IP].[Id] AND [RecruitmentIP].[dbo].[tbl_IP].[IPFrom] = [RecruitmentIP].[dbo].[tbl_IP].[IPFrom] AND [RecruitmentIP].[dbo].[tbl_IP].[IPTo] = [RecruitmentIP].[dbo].[tbl_IP].[IPTo] AND [RecruitmentIP].[dbo].[tbl_IP].[CountryCode] = [RecruitmentIP].[dbo].[tbl_IP].[CountryCode] AND [RecruitmentIP].[dbo].[tbl_IP].[CountryName] = [RecruitmentIP].[dbo].[tbl_IP].[CountryName] AND [RecruitmentIP].[dbo].[tbl_IP].[Region] = [RecruitmentIP].[dbo].[tbl_IP].[Region] AND [RecruitmentIP].[dbo].[tbl_IP].[City] = [RecruitmentIP].[dbo].[tbl_IP].[City]"><Logical Operation="AND"><ScalarOperator><Compare CompareOp="EQ"><ScalarOperator><Identifier><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="Id"/></Identifier></ScalarOperator><ScalarOperator><Identifier><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="Id"/></Identifier></ScalarOperator></Compare></ScalarOperator><ScalarOperator><Compare CompareOp="IS"><ScalarOperator><Identifier><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="IPFrom"/></Identifier></ScalarOperator><ScalarOperator><Identifier><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="IPFrom"/></Identifier></ScalarOperator></Compare></ScalarOperator><ScalarOperator><Compare CompareOp="IS"><ScalarOperator><Identifier><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="IPTo"/></Identifier></ScalarOperator><ScalarOperator><Identifier><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="IPTo"/></Identifier></ScalarOperator></Compare></ScalarOperator><ScalarOperator><Compare CompareOp="IS"><ScalarOperator><Identifier><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="CountryCode"/></Identifier></ScalarOperator><ScalarOperator><Identifier><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="CountryCode"/></Identifier></ScalarOperator></Compare></ScalarOperator><ScalarOperator><Compare CompareOp="IS"><ScalarOperator><Identifier><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="CountryName"/></Identifier></ScalarOperator><ScalarOperator><Identifier><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="CountryName"/></Identifier></ScalarOperator></Compare></ScalarOperator><ScalarOperator><Compare CompareOp="IS"><ScalarOperator><Identifier><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="Region"/></Identifier></ScalarOperator><ScalarOperator><Identifier><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="Region"/></Identifier></ScalarOperator></Compare></ScalarOperator><ScalarOperator><Compare CompareOp="IS"><ScalarOperator><Identifier><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="City"/></Identifier></ScalarOperator><ScalarOperator><Identifier><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="City"/></Identifier></ScalarOperator></Compare></ScalarOperator></Logical></ScalarOperator></Predicate><RelOp NodeId="1" PhysicalOp="Filter" LogicalOp="Filter" EstimateRows="1" EstimateIO="0" EstimateCPU="4.8e-007" AvgRowSize="86" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="226.399" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0"><OutputList><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="Id"/><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="IPFrom"/><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="IPTo"/><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="CountryCode"/><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="CountryName"/><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="Region"/><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="City"/></OutputList><Filter StartupExpression="0"><RelOp NodeId="2" PhysicalOp="Sort" LogicalOp="TopN Sort" EstimateRows="1" EstimateIO="163.119" EstimateCPU="29.7123" AvgRowSize="86" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="226.399" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0"><OutputList><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="Id"/><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="IPFrom"/><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="IPTo"/><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="CountryCode"/><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="CountryName"/><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="Region"/><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="City"/></OutputList><MemoryFractions Input="0" Output="0"/><TopSort Distinct="0" Rows="1"><OrderBy><OrderByColumn Ascending="1"><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="IPTo"/></OrderByColumn></OrderBy><RelOp NodeId="3" PhysicalOp="Clustered Index Scan" LogicalOp="Clustered Index Scan" EstimateRows="1.02843e+006" EstimateIO="28.1505" EstimateCPU="3.77105" AvgRowSize="86" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="31.9216" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0"><OutputList><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="Id"/><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="IPFrom"/><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="IPTo"/><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="CountryCode"/><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="CountryName"/><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="Region"/><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="City"/></OutputList><IndexScan Ordered="0" ForcedIndex="0" NoExpandHint="0"><DefinedValues><DefinedValue><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="Id"/></DefinedValue><DefinedValue><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="IPFrom"/></DefinedValue><DefinedValue><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="IPTo"/></DefinedValue><DefinedValue><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="CountryCode"/></DefinedValue><DefinedValue><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="CountryName"/></DefinedValue><DefinedValue><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="Region"/></DefinedValue><DefinedValue><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="City"/></DefinedValue></DefinedValues><Object Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Index="[PK_tbl_IP2]" TableReferenceId="1"/><Predicate><ScalarOperator ScalarString="[@ip]&lt;=[RecruitmentIP].[dbo].[tbl_IP].[IPTo]"><Compare CompareOp="LE"><ScalarOperator><Identifier><ColumnReference Column="@ip"/></Identifier></ScalarOperator><ScalarOperator><Identifier><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="IPTo"/></Identifier></ScalarOperator></Compare></ScalarOperator></Predicate></IndexScan></RelOp></TopSort></RelOp><Predicate><ScalarOperator ScalarString="[RecruitmentIP].[dbo].[tbl_IP].[IPFrom]&lt;=[@ip]"><Compare CompareOp="LE"><ScalarOperator><Identifier><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="IPFrom"/></Identifier></ScalarOperator><ScalarOperator><Identifier><ColumnReference Column="@ip"/></Identifier></ScalarOperator></Compare></ScalarOperator></Predicate></Filter></RelOp><RelOp NodeId="5" PhysicalOp="Filter" LogicalOp="Filter" EstimateRows="1" EstimateIO="0" EstimateCPU="4.8e-007" AvgRowSize="86" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.00985397" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0"><OutputList><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="Id"/><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="IPFrom"/><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="IPTo"/><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="CountryCode"/><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="CountryName"/><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="Region"/><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="City"/></OutputList><Filter StartupExpression="0"><RelOp NodeId="6" PhysicalOp="Top" LogicalOp="Top" EstimateRows="1" EstimateIO="0" EstimateCPU="1e-007" AvgRowSize="86" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.00985349" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0"><OutputList><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="Id"/><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="IPFrom"/><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="IPTo"/><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="CountryCode"/><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="CountryName"/><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="Region"/><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="City"/></OutputList><Top RowCount="0" IsPercent="0" WithTies="0"><TopExpression><ScalarOperator ScalarString="(1)"><Const ConstValue="(1)"/></ScalarOperator></TopExpression><RelOp NodeId="7" PhysicalOp="Nested Loops" LogicalOp="Inner Join" EstimateRows="1" EstimateIO="0" EstimateCPU="4.29882" AvgRowSize="86" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.00985339" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0"><OutputList><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="Id"/><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="IPFrom"/><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="IPTo"/><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="CountryCode"/><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="CountryName"/><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="Region"/><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="City"/></OutputList><NestedLoops Optimized="0" WithOrderedPrefetch="1"><OuterReferences><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="Id"/><ColumnReference Column="Expr1006"/></OuterReferences><RelOp NodeId="9" PhysicalOp="Index Seek" LogicalOp="Index Seek" EstimateRows="1" EstimateIO="2.45201" EstimateCPU="1.13142" AvgRowSize="27" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.0032831" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0"><OutputList><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="Id"/><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="IPFrom"/><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="IPTo"/></OutputList><IndexScan Ordered="1" ScanDirection="BACKWARD" ForcedIndex="0" NoExpandHint="0"><DefinedValues><DefinedValue><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="Id"/></DefinedValue><DefinedValue><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="IPFrom"/></DefinedValue><DefinedValue><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="IPTo"/></DefinedValue></DefinedValues><Object Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Index="[idx_ipfrom_ipto]" TableReferenceId="2"/><SeekPredicates><SeekPredicate><EndRange ScanType="LE"><RangeColumns><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="IPFrom"/></RangeColumns><RangeExpressions><ScalarOperator ScalarString="[@ip]"><Identifier><ColumnReference Column="@ip"/></Identifier></ScalarOperator></RangeExpressions></EndRange></SeekPredicate></SeekPredicates></IndexScan></RelOp><RelOp NodeId="11" PhysicalOp="Clustered Index Seek" LogicalOp="Clustered Index Seek" EstimateRows="1" EstimateIO="0.003125" EstimateCPU="0.0001581" AvgRowSize="373" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.00669221" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="1" EstimateRewinds="0.797604"><OutputList><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="CountryCode"/><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="CountryName"/><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="Region"/><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="City"/></OutputList><IndexScan Lookup="1" Ordered="1" ScanDirection="FORWARD" ForcedIndex="0" NoExpandHint="0"><DefinedValues><DefinedValue><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="CountryCode"/></DefinedValue><DefinedValue><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="CountryName"/></DefinedValue><DefinedValue><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="Region"/></DefinedValue><DefinedValue><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="City"/></DefinedValue></DefinedValues><Object Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Index="[PK_tbl_IP2]" TableReferenceId="-1"/><SeekPredicates><SeekPredicate><Prefix ScanType="EQ"><RangeColumns><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="Id"/></RangeColumns><RangeExpressions><ScalarOperator ScalarString="[RecruitmentIP].[dbo].[tbl_IP].[Id]"><Identifier><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="Id"/></Identifier></ScalarOperator></RangeExpressions></Prefix></SeekPredicate></SeekPredicates></IndexScan></RelOp></NestedLoops></RelOp></Top></RelOp><Predicate><ScalarOperator ScalarString="[RecruitmentIP].[dbo].[tbl_IP].[IPTo]&gt;=[@ip]"><Compare CompareOp="GE"><ScalarOperator><Identifier><ColumnReference Database="[RecruitmentIP]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_IP]" Column="IPTo"/></Identifier></ScalarOperator><ScalarOperator><Identifier><ColumnReference Column="@ip"/></Identifier></ScalarOperator></Compare></ScalarOperator></Predicate></Filter></RelOp></NestedLoops></RelOp></QueryPlan></StmtSimple><StmtSimple StatementText="&#xa;set statistics time off" StatementId="4" StatementCompId="4" StatementType="SET STATS"/></Statements></Batch></BatchSequence></ShowPlanXML>
```

Comment: As it stands that Query is missing an `ORDER  BY'. Select `Top 1` ordered by what?

Comment: Is this data relatively static? Might be an opportunity for the client to cache the data.

Comment: @Martin Smith,  there is only one row returned for each query so TOP 1 isn't necessary but using it knocks 50ms of the query time

Comment: @JohnC, yes the data will probably only change a few times per year.  Are you suggesting caching the whole db or just individual results?

Comment: @tt83  - Can you post the Actual Execution Plan XML so we can see the expensive operations. This definitely looks like something that should be able to be resolved by simply adding the correct index.

Comment: @Martin Smith, I've edit the original post to include the xml execution plan.

Comment: yes, I'm assuming you're using a .NET client here. Caching the whole table contents and querying that instead of going to the DB everytime. May seem like a lot of data, but memory is cheap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does this perform? I'm hoping that it should use an index seek on ipto to quickly resolve the top part, an index seek on ipfrom to resolve the bottom part and 2 (or possibly one) bookmark lookups to get the rest of the columns to return.

```
SELECT id, ipfrom, ipto, countrycode, countryname,region,city FROM
(
SELECT TOP 1 id, ipfrom, ipto, countrycode, countryname,region,city
FROM tbl_ip 
WHERE @ip <= ipto
ORDER BY ipto
INTERSECT
SELECT TOP 1 id, ipfrom, ipto, countrycode, countryname,region,city
FROM tbl_ip 
WHERE ipfrom <= @ip
ORDER BY ipfrom DESC
) ip
```

Comment: ok, i've reposted the execution plan.  the plan i posted earlier wasn't using the indexes because I had actually taken them off.  the new plan is using the indexes.

Comment: @tt83 - Can you confirm whether my assumption about correlation between the columns is correct or not?

Comment: just checked out your assumption that ipto in one row is previous to ipfrom in the next row and you are correct!

Comment: i've tried that query and it executes in about double the time the original query took unfortunately..

Comment: @tt83 can you post the execution plan for that one please?

Comment: @tt83 I'd first see Neil Poulton's answer and see if that helps. If not half of that plan you posted looks alright. It just needs an index on 'ipto' and then should perform fine (the composite index on from and to can be used for the bottom part of the query but not the top part). Infact if no other queries are relying on the composite index 2 separate indexes. One on 'ipfrom'and the other on 'ipto' would be the best combination for the query above.

Comment: @tt83, Martin is right - the culprit for slow execution of the above query is ORDER BY ipto, assuming only one composite index (ipfrom, ipto). (so you can expect gain if you separate indexes, if the above query run only twice as slow while building the index for sorting). Furthermore I got the same query in my answer - but only using ipfrom since I assumed the ip ranges not overlapping but covering a some bigger range (in another words ipto equals ipfrom of the next row). In that case you don't need two indexes (you don't even need two columns strictly speaking).

Comment: thanks guys,  following Martin's advice to add one index on (ipfrom, ipto) and another just on ipto, my original query now takes just 1 ms!!  thanks for all the answers!

Comment: by the way, where did you guys learn so much about the inner workings of indexes from?  i haven't been able to find much useful info on the web...

Comment: @tt83, Martin: I am being picky today; I updated my answer - I claim that you don't need two indexes nor interesection. @tt83, Re indexes, a combination of wikipedia, C.J.Date (Introduction to Database Systems) and examining execution plans across RDBMSes did a trick for me.

Comment: @Unreason - Absolutely correct. Precisely because of the correlation only one index is needed.

Comment: @tt83 You might find this question useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022424/recommended-book-for-sql-server-query-optimisation

Comment: @Lankymart - It was a question called "Recommended book for SQL Server query optimisation" Now deleted so only accessible to 10K users.

Answer (score 2):

I think the main reason why the query is slow even with index *ipfrom, ipto* is that the engine can not use the index properly.

It takes the first condition `ipfrom <= @ip` and is able to use index for that, however this inequality has a low selection and if your ip ranges cover all ips and are not overlapping then for the index has only one *ipto* entry for each *ipfrom* index leaf.

That is not so useful and it ends up doing full index scan (assumption1).

So, to speed it up there are several tricks

1) If `select @ip_max_delta = max(ipto-ipfrom)` is not to big (~1000 records) you can add `WHERE ipfrom > (@ip - @ip_max_delta)` (this is directly usable only if ip's are stored as int). This will work well with any index starting with *ipfrom*

2)

```
SELECT TOP 1 id, ipfrom, ipto, countrycode, countryname,region,city
FROM tbl_ip 
WHERE ipfrom <= @ip
ORDER BY ipfrom DESC
```

This should return really quickly (especially if you cluster on ipfrom and you should as your data rarely changes).

If the above does not return quickly can you test the execution time (and plan) on the following query, just for reference

```
SELECT id, ipfrom, ipto, countrycode, countryname,region,city
FROM tbl_ip 
WHERE ipfrom = @ip
```

(choose existing @ip that exists in ipfrom column)

**EDIT2**: Re Martin's solution

I don't see reason to **a)** use intersection/subquery and **b)** to maintain two indexes

```
SELECT TOP 1 id, ipfrom, ipto, countrycode, countryname,region,city
FROM tbl_ip 
WHERE ipfrom <= @ip
ORDER BY ipfrom DESC
```

Should return the same as Martin's query if there is correlation between ipfrom and ipto in consecutive rows. If not then additional condition can be applied directly

```
SELECT TOP 1 id, ipfrom, ipto, countrycode, countryname,region,city
FROM tbl_ip 
WHERE ipfrom <= @ip AND @ip <= ipto
ORDER BY ipfrom DESC
```

This query is quite similar to the starting one, but the ORDER BY should allow parser to choose better plan (unverfied). If it does not then

```
SELECT id, ipfrom, ipto, countrycode, countryname,region,city
FROM
(SELECT TOP 1 id, ipfrom, ipto, countrycode, countryname,region,city
FROM tbl_ip 
WHERE ipfrom <= @ip
ORDER BY ipfrom DESC) s
WHERE @ip <= ipto
```

Should do the trick and would require only index on ipfrom.

Answer (score 1):

I see two ways to reduce execution time

1.Simple one would be to Cache whole 3m of records and use .NET native Datasets to retrieve wanted item in IP range. This will obviously eat your server CPU but you won't make 10 calls to DB every second.

2.Harder one would be to split IPs to different tables like IPRanges1 .... IPRanges9. So once you get user IP and want to query other details, you just pass to query another param with first digit of IP. This will reduce looping through 3M to 3m/9 (or something like that). Reduce in execution time will be obvious. If you combine it with Caching method you will end up with something proper.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to the WHERE clause
**AND ipfrom <= ipto**

Comment: Or not. On original index (ipfrom, ipto) the above condition would not help (especially since each ipfrom leaf on the index would have maximum one entry for ipto; which means that the index will have to be scanned).

Answer (score 1):

Is your clustered index on id? If so, you could maybe change it to ipfrom, ipto.

Comment: Not really the issue though. It's only returning one row.

Comment: And it's not going to be able to traverse the clustered index faster?

Comment: Whilst this will help slightly the main problem with the query is that the query optimiser doesn't realise that there is a correlation between the 'ipfrom' and 'ipto' columns so scans a lot of rows unnecessarily.

Comment: Yes, now I look at the execution plan I see what you mean

Answer (score 0):

What are your indexes?  Would it help if you had one covering index?  So ipfrom, ipto on one index?  Could then even "include" id, countrycode, countryname, region, and city fields in that index so system does not have to go to data pages to get that data.

-Krip

Comment: There is just one index which combines both the ipfrom & ipto columns.  Interestingly it makes no difference to the execution time if I remove the indexes from the table.  I haven't tried including the other fields. I'll give that a go shortly.

Comment: also worth knowing if you have a clustered index and what fields that covers.

Answer (score 0):

If ip ranges start at powers of 2 (and they should), you could exploit the fact that ip = ipfrom or ip = ipfrom & 11...10 or ip = ipfrom & 11...00, etc...

32 index lookups should be faster than a index range scan.

Just a thought.

Comment: this looks interesting but it's a little bit beyond my knowledge to be honest.  would you be able to do a sample query based on the your post?

Answer (score 0):

there is a more simple and logical solution:

1) create an extra column in your ip_country table:
Arange which is actually ip_from / 16777216

2) create a clustered index on Arange, ip_from

3) use "[ipaddress]/16777216 =Arange and [ipaddress] between ip_from and ip_to" in your query

Answer (score 0):

if you are sure that the resulting data is just one row, then you can use ForceSeek option

Comment: could you please explain in detail

Answer (score -1):

May be review possibility to change architecture? (Using MSSQL hints me that you can use .Net) 
Since you use readonly database review some: in memory database. Or try OracleCoherence for .Net (http://coherence.oracle.com/)

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look into this.

Answer (score -2):

You probably need to separate out the data into two tables: IPData (ipfrom, ipto, locationid) and LocationData (locationid, countryname, city, etc)

I would change the where clause to:

```
WHERE @ip BETWEEN ipfrom AND ipto
```