# How to iterate a collection of records and "re-associate" dates whenever a record is added or changed

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two Date columns, `EffDate` and `TermDate`. When a record is inserted for the very first time, `TermDate` is `NULL`. When additional records are added, the first record's `TermDate` should now be assigned the value of the second record's `EffDate`, assuming #2's `EffDate` is later than the first. If the second record's `EffDate` is before #1's, then #2 should have its `TermDate` set to #1's `EffDate`. Basically, any time a record is inserted or updated, the database needs to re-evaluate all of the records and link them so that there is only the smallest possible span of time between all of the dates.

I found this SO post: [Creating new date field dynamically from next row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365514/creating-new-date-field-dynamically-from-next-row)

But the selected answer doesn't quite work for me. This is the query I'm using:

```
UPDATE T1 SET
    T1.[TermDate] = @aEffDate
FROM [Information] T1
WHERE T1.[InformationID] IN (SELECT ISNULL(T1.InformationID, 0)
    FROM [Information] T1 INNER JOIN [Information] T2 on T1.InformationID = T2.InformationID - 1
    WHERE  T1.InformationID <>  @aInformationID
        AND T1.[DeletedBy] IS NULL
        AND T1.[DeletedOn] IS NULL
        AND T1.Code = @aCode
        AND T1.TermDate IS NULL
        AND T1.EffDate < @aEffDate)
```

Then when I load up the software and insert a new record, it does not seem to go back and "update" all the previous records as I was hoping. Here is the output after inserting a few records with random `EffDate`'s into the database:

[image]

**Output & Analysis**

```
    | InformationID |  EffDate  |  TermDate  | IsGood |  ShouldBe  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
 1  |    5756       | 07/19/15  |  09/19/15  |   N    |   07/25/15 |
 2  |    5757       | 06/30/15  |  07/10/15  |   Y    |     N/A    |
 3  |    5758       | 08/01/15  |  09/19/15  |   Y    |     N/A    |
 4  |    5759       | 07/25/15  |  09/19/15  |   N    |   08/01/15 |
 5  |    5760       | 09/19/15  |    NULL    |   Y    |     N/A    |
 6  |    5761       | 07/10/15  |    NULL    |   N    |   07/19/15 |
```

I need it so that whenever a new record is added, it'll re-evaluate all the records associated with a given `Code` and make sure each date points to the next "closest" date, so that there are no overlapping `EffDate` and `TermDate` ranges.

I realize that, at the very least, I need to remove `AND T1.TermDate IS NULL` because that's preventing it from re-evaluating two records when a third record with an `EffDate` between the other two's range is inserted. But I'm not sure how I should evaluate `TermDate` so that records with existing dates will be appropriately re-evaluated and assigned a date if necessary.

Comment: Well, this is more than bad. What should happen when there are two same EffDate?

Comment: The answer that you refer to has an inferior answer.  I've provided a safer answer.

Comment: @PeterRing The software does not allow two records with the same `EffDate`

Comment: @GordonLinoff Your answer there simply overwrites every record's `TermDate` with the `EffDate` of the last record I enter, including the record being added.

Answer (score 1):

```
update tb
set tb.termdate=tb2.effdate
from InfoTable tb
left outer join InfoTable tb2 on tb2.effdate>tb.effdate
left outer join InfoTable tb3 on tb3.effdate<tb2.effdate and tb3.effdate>tb.effdate
where tb3.effdate is null
```

This will: (A) select all rows in your table `tb`; (B) join all rows from the same table `tb2` with EffDate greater than `tb.EffDate`; and (C) again join all rows from the table `tb3` with `EffDate > tb.EffDate AND EffDate<tb2.EffDate`

The final condition `tb3.EffDate is null` will make sure that there is no other record in the table with EffDate between `tb.EffDate` and `tb2.EffDate`

Comment: Highlighted rows [seen here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/SQyYD.png) are incorrect using this approach. Row 3 should end on the 5th, Row 6 end on 30th, row 8 on the 25th and row 9 on the 12th.

Comment: After running the query you should only have ONE null on the TermDate column

Comment: You are correct, there *should* be only 1. But instead there are 4. This query gets run after every `insert` or `update` on the table, so after it gets run upon the final insert there *should* only be 1 null. But that is not the case, unfortunately.

Comment: You dont need to run it after every insert. You can run it only once at the end of the batch. Try inserting all data and then run the query separately.

Comment: The query in my original question is the final part of a stored procedure responsible for the inserting or updating of records. So I'm just looking to modify that to perform the desired behavior mentioned in my question. It's not really done in a batch process, as users don't add data to this *too* frequently.

Comment: First, make sure that you have a working update query, by testing it outside of the procedure. Only then you can begin to test the procedure itself. This query works just fine as long as there are no duplicate EffDate values. If you DO have duplicates, you need to adjust the conditions accordingly.

Comment: If I run the update on its own, after I've added all of my data, it does work (I do need to tweak the parameters, as the very last record actually isn't `NULL` as expected). But the problem is if I enter 9/1, 9/3, 9/5, and then 8/30, 9/2, 9/4, 9/6 the second 'batch' of entries don't get their `TermDates` set for some reason. Then again, if I run that `update` on its own it fixes them. Not really sure what's causing this...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94164/discussion-between-andy-and-sab669).